# Getting undefined index: status in Yajra Datatable with Laravel 6.xx

Tags: php, yajra-datatable, laravel-6.2

The first table "Offers" I store there offers details. If offer status = public then everyone able to access and status will be shown "Approved" in Yajra Datatable.

Otherwise, If offer status = request, the user can request for access. when they submit requests for access, It will be stored in Offer Request table with user id and offer id and with status = 0 means in yajra datatable status pending. then admin can set status = 1 mean in yajra datatable status approve.

I'm getting this error within this code.

NB: Sorry for bad English

```
->editColumn('status', function(Offer $offer) {

                if($offer->offer_permission == 'public')
                {
                    $status = '<span class="badge badge-primary">Approve</span>';

                }elseif($offer->offer_permission == 'request')
                {
                    $checkstatus= OfferRequest::select('status')->where('offer_id', $offer->id )->where('user_id', Auth::id())->pluck('status')->toArray();

                      if($checkstatus['status'] == 0)
                         {
                                $status = '<span class="badge badge-secondary">Pending</span>';

                         }elseif ($checkstatus['status'] == '1')
                         {
                                $status = '<span class="badge badge-primary">Approve</span>';

                         }elseif ($checkstatus['status'] == '2')
                         {
                                $status = '<span class="badge badge-danger">Rejected</span>';

                         }elseif ($checkstatus['status'] == '3')
                         {
                                $status = '<span class="badge badge-danger">Blocked</span>';

                         }else
                         {
                             $status = '<a href="' . route('offers.show', $offer->id) .'"><span class="badge badge-secondary">Apply Now</span></a>';
                         }

                }

                return $status;

            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should to add checkpoint for checkstatus variable that it's empty or not.

```
editColumn('status', function(Offer $offer) {

            if($offer->offer_permission == 'public')
            {
                $status = '<span class="badge badge-primary">Approve</span>';

            }elseif($offer->offer_permission == 'request')
            {
                $checkstatus= OfferRequest::select('status')->where('offer_id', $offer->id )->where('user_id', Auth::id())->pluck('status')->toArray();
                if(empty($checkstatus)){
                  if($checkstatus['status'] == 0)
                     {
                            $status = '<span class="badge badge-secondary">Pending</span>';

                     }elseif ($checkstatus['status'] == '1')
                     {
                            $status = '<span class="badge badge-primary">Approve</span>';

                     }elseif ($checkstatus['status'] == '2')
                     {
                            $status = '<span class="badge badge-danger">Rejected</span>';

                     }elseif ($checkstatus['status'] == '3')
                     {
                            $status = '<span class="badge badge-danger">Blocked</span>';

                     }else
                     {
                         $status = '<a href="' . route('offers.show', $offer->id) .'"><span class="badge badge-secondary">Apply Now</span></a>';
                     }
                }else{
                    $status = '<a href="' . route('offers.show', $offer->id) .'"><span class="badge badge-secondary">Apply Now</span></a>';
                }

            }

            return $status;

        })
```

Try it!